# asp.net redirect to another location than set in navigateURL

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

in my asp.net website I have menu control and there are those items:

```
<asp:menuitem ... navigateURL="~/Admin/admin.aspx">
<asp:menuitem ... navigateURL="~/Admin/search.aspx">
```

I want force the asp.net think (or display in web browser adress bar), that I am on admin.aspx, but actually be redirected to search.aspx. Is it somehow possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to do it, because I have main menu in my webapp and menuitem, which points to current page, is highlighted. However, when I browse into some section under Admin, highlighting disappears, even if I am still in Admin section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing that with the markup you showed, no, it's not possible. You'll need to either use an `<iframe>` setting the `src` property via javascript or you do it from code-behind using `Server.Transfer` as opposed to `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: I tried my own custom logic and it works, however it didn't solved my problem. (comment)

Comment: Now when I am on search.aspx, browser shows admin.aspx, but webapp knows, that I am on search.aspx :D

Comment: Maybe consider this navigateurl="~/Admin/admin.aspx?mode=search" this would be perfect, but howto force webapp to show search.aspx ?

Comment: @polohy You can't, you cannot control the browser's address bar. Again, the only 2 ways to achieve the effect you want are explained in my answer. You can't programmatically change the Browser's address bar so passing parameters in the query string won't buy you anything

Comment: problem solved. just had to add this.Menu1.Items[0].Selected = true. Now I can use force to highlight Admin menuitem when I am in admin section. Thus I don't need to control url. However thanks

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting sounds like it's what you are after:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Failing that you might be able to build some custom logic into your page and use `Server.Transfer` to change page, without changing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [customized routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application) if you would like, but that will still display "search.aspx" in the address bar.  If you want to fake the admin.aspx as search.aspx, then add your search controls in to the admin.aspx page and hide the admin controls.  If you are trying to "spoof" admin.aspx, like you would an e-mail address or something, then I would direct to not StackOverflow.